# Mapping domain to webadress

Tags: apache-http-server, ubuntu-12.04, webserver, administration

im currently trying to set up an apache client on a ubuntu root server.

i have set up the apache and it is running, as i can access the "It works" page while doing it directly with the ip belonging to the root. but the domain that came with the server wont work as intended.

I have changed the hostname in /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts to the address under which the server should be accessible.

But when i try to access the server with the domain that came with it it just shows

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.

so i assume its not correctly redirected to the ip.

i am sort of new to this. A tutorial on how to set this up would be appreciated.

Comment: If you dig the record, does it return the correct IP? If it does not, you first need to make sure the correct A record is in place for that domain name.

Comment: what do you mean by, dig the record? can you be more specific :)

Comment: dig is a command: http://linux.die.net/man/1/dig